# Adding date/time using JavaScript to my asp.net user control

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have a user control where I was getting the server time and doing using a AJAX timer to update it every second. This was very slow and I've been told it is better to do it on the client side.

So I came up with this...but it isn't working. Any suggestions?

```
    <%@ Control Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="DateTime.ascx.vb" Inherits="UserControls_WebUserControl" %>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        getDate();
    };

    function getDate() {
        var dt = new Date();
        var element = document.getElementById("client_time");

        element.text = dt.toDateString();
    }


</script>
   <form name="headerForm">
   <asp:Table Width="100%" ID="formatTable" runat="server">
            <asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableCell ColumnSpan="2">
                    <asp:Image ImageUrl="~/Logo.jpg" ID="Image1" runat="server" />
                </asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    <input type="text" size="10" maxlength="10" value="" name="client_time"  />

                </asp:TableCell>

            </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Table>
    </form>
```

Comment: You have filled out the `name` field of the element, but it lacks the `id` needed to find it via `getElementById`. Also, `.text` won't do anything, you need to set its `value` attribute.

Comment: I made those changes and the date is showing up! The text box isn't wide enough to show all of it though. Is storing it in a text box the best idea? I don't want to see the graphic of a text box, it would be nice to mesh into the background. Also, any suggestions on adding the time? Thanks!

Comment: You could put it inside of whatever element you wish to, even the table cell itself would work (with `innerHTML`). As for time: http://www.quackit.com/javascript/tutorial/javascript_date_and_time.cfm

Comment: Thank worked great! If you want to submit this as an Answer, I will confirm it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have filled out the `name` field of the element, but it lacks the id needed to find it via `getElementById`. Also, `.text` won't do anything, you need to set its `value` attribute.

Since your input has a limit of 10 characters you might try removing that to show the full date string or you could instead simply write to the table cell with `innerHTML` or some such method.

To get time in a human readable format you can take a look at: http://www.quackit.com/javascript/tutorial/javascript_date_and_time.cfm